# Adding new row to jQuery Datatables is changing a currency string, $0.00, to a number, 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with three columns: item #, desc, and price:

```
<table id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Item #</th>
         <th>Desc</th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1234</td>
         <td>Widget A</td>
         <td>$23.15</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I initialize the datatables plugin on my table:

```
myDatatable = $("#myTable").DataTable({
    paging: false,
    dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp'
});
```

***EDITED***
When I add a new row to the table:

```
rowDet = [];    
rowDet[0] = '9876';
rowDet[1] = 'Widget B';
rowDet[2] = '$1.00';

myDatatable.row.add(rowDet).node();

myDatatable.draw(false); //<-- I forgot to show this
```

The new column is added but the price column has lost it's string currency format, eg: '$1.00' is now just 1.

**I don't know why or how to prevent this?**

FYI - this is the build of datatables I am using:
https://datatables.net/download/#bs/jszip-2.5.0/pdfmake-0.1.32/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-html5-1.5.1/b-print-1.5.1/fc-3.2.4/fh-3.1.3/sc-1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `myDatatable.row.add(rowDet).draw(false);` that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The given example was a simplified version of what my actual code looked like and it turns out that it is working as shown in the example.  The problem was a typo in my code.